# Loading animation with webform c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, animation, webforms, progress-bar

I have a huge webform application with asp.net c #.
I would like to put a nice loading animation during loads.
I tried with Jquery and "BlockUI" with a setTimeout and I added a "loader" class on submit buttons.

```
 $('.loader').click(function () {
                $.blockUI({
                    css: {
                        backgroundColor: '#3e5b74',
                    }
                });
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 60000);
            });
```

But it's not reliable. I have a lot of pages which contain buttons. With a gif, javascript works one time in two and if I click a second time in a button, the animation goes on even if page is loaded.
I search a solution with only asp.net and C#, not js or jquery. And I would like that affects the entire application not just one or two buttons.

In fact I would like exactly the behaviour of the little wheel in the tab. It's not possible to copy this event? :p

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean something while your page is doing a postback? Well, actually in that case you have two pages - the old one, and the new one.

Comment: Yes, it's during postback. For the moment, JS works because when second page is loaded, the jquery function is reset. But it's not a very good solution

Comment: Well you'll have to use some kind of JS, otherwise your animation will never get un-loaded. Might you be better spending the time to see if you can make your page load faster?

Comment: Hum it's not really possible because my application is used to make big treatments and calculations. It seems better to do an animation.

Comment: Well I doubt that _no_ improvement can be made. I've seen, and written, lots of applications which require dozens of complex calculations to be done before the right content can be displayed, but which still load within a second or two. It depends where and when you do the calcs, and how efficient the code is, and also how bloated the UI code is. But anyway I'll leave that for you to think about.

Comment: In the meantime, it's not really clear exactly what we can do about your animation - what do you mean it "works one time in two"? This sounds a bit odd. Can you make a JSFiddle which reproduces the problem, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help anyway, I'm not alone in working on this application. But yes, even if it was not the question, some pages should be reviewed. When I said "It works one time in two" it concerned an animated gif. Sometimes the display is good, sometimes gif is cut in half or stop instantly. This is a javascript problem

Answer (score 0):

Ok so no solution :/ It's strange that there is no simple and effective solution in C# to propose postback loading between pages, while even my mouse cursor does it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stupid. Indeed even if it's more complicated, using an overlayer with ajax (updatePanel/progressPanel) is the best way to do this.